# Excessões e conexão de banco de dados

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, conexão

Tenho um código que faz uma query em um banco de dados.
Se ocorrer uma excessão por timeout por exemplo durante a execução da query, o código de fechamento da conexão e consequente devolução da conexão para o pool não ocorrerá, devo usar um try-finally para mesmo com excessão passar pelo código de fechamento da conexão?

Comment: É considerada boa prática você fechar conexões com banco no bloco `finally` justamente para que, em caso de sucesso ou erro, ela sempre ser fechada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> devo usar um try-finally para mesmo com excessão passar pelo código de fechamento da conexão?

Sim.

Se você estiver usando Java 7 ou superior pode usar o [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).